# How to find streak from date in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection called journals. It contains a field called "createdAt" which represents the ISO date at which the journal entry was created. We can group the journals for each user via the "userid" and get all journal entries for a user. I want to calculate a journal streak ( day basis ) for the user. Streak is essentially the number of consecutive days he is currently actively creating journals ( indicated by the "createdAt" field). There can be more than 1 journal entry a day but streak just counts as 1 for that day .

Example for how the date entry looks like is
[image]

I have a nodeJS backend using mongoose to interact with mongoDB . Is there a mongoDB query that I can write to do this?